# PC to TV via HDMI problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I just bought a new PC for home use that I wanted to connect to a TV via HDMI cable, but there are so many issues I had to ask for help.

The PC is with integrated Intel (I3-4330) graphic card (motherboard is Gigabyte B85M-DS3H / 1150 if important). The TV is Sharp Aquos LC-32LD145V which has digital TV tuner connected from digital TV provider.

I want to connect the TV as second monitor to watch movies on the bigger screen while using the PC for browsing and such.

The first issue is when I connect both ends of the HDMI the television signal gets all flickery and has a static noise (something similar if you turn any speakers on and touch the back metal of the PC case with the plug). This results in TV being unwatchable unless HDMI cable is removed. The same goes for the PC monitor - when HDMI cable is plugged it also gets flickery. It might has something to do with refresh rates, but the graphics driver does not have options to change them (much).

Even if we put these problems aside the TV somehow cuts the top, bottom and sides of the desktop (around 50px each) and by my knowledge there is no setting on the TV itself which can fix that.

Alternatively I've a VGA to VGA cable which I can plug into the DVI port of the PC via DVI to VGA converter and plug the other end into the TV. In this case everything seems fine, however I cannot set the resolution for the TV to full HD (1080p) - the screen goes black.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: have you tried swapping the HDMI cables and ports with the tv tuner?

Comment: Make sure that the TV can accept the resolution and frequency you are outputting (1080p 60Hz, 1920x1080 60Hz) [Source](http://cdn.cnetcontent.com/18/07/18072f3e-10eb-48ad-b557-ee283d479977.pdf)

Comment: Try a new HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

1. do you have the correct driver for your graphic card? looks like you can find it [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4731#dl)
2. your hdmi cable, what version is it? your card is 1.4 it looks like.. have you tried a different cable, or tried this cable on another system?
3. do the TV and PC get power from same source? consider UPS for cleaner power
4. if TV does not have some tuning capability (to fix error in size or position), I hope the graphic driver does. try to change the "mode" of the TV.

Answer (score 0):

Very very late to the party here, but I experienced the second of these two problems, i.e. the clipping of a border around the display when connecting an LG TV to my laptop via HDMI.

I was able to fix it by looking in the settings menu, LG have an option called "Just Scan" which defaulted to off, but when turned on caused the display to correctly render the 3840 * 2160 signal the laptop was passing to it.

For anyone else that comes across this question looking for a solution to "border clipping" as I call it, try checking the TV settings menu, there may be something in there that will fix it.